# 5.2 Eloquent Javascript - 3rd Edition

Tags: javascript, function, loops, for-loop, higher-order-functions

Relatively new at programming, looking for an explanation of a question in Chapter 5 of Eloquent Javascript.

> **Your own loop** Write a higher-order function loop that provides something like a for loop statement. It takes a value, a test
>   function, an update function, and a body function. Each iteration, it
>   first runs the test function on the current loop value and stops if
>   that returns false. Then it calls the body function, giving it the
>   current value. Finally, it calls the update function to create a new
>   value and starts from the beginning.
>
> When defining the function, you can use a regular loop to do the
>   actual looping.
>
> `loop(3, n => n > 0, n => n - 1, console.log); // → 3 // → 2 // → 1`

The answer:

```
function loop(start, test, update, body) {
  for (let value = start; test(value); value = update(value)) {
    body(value);
  }
}

loop(3, n => n > 0, n => n - 1, console.log);
// → 3
// → 2
// → 1
```

Looking for a walkthrough of what the code is doing. Any help to clearly understand this problem would be helpful.

Comment: aaaah this book is my love <3 if you are new to programming i recommend you don't make Eloquent javascript your first book

Comment: What is it that you're having trouble understanding?

Comment: `value` starts at `3` and is referenced by `n` in the two functions where it is passed in from the calls.

Comment: visually it's confusing but I am trying to wrap my head around it. This is how I'm trying to look at this loop 

`function loop(3, n => n > 0, n => n - 1, console.log) {
for (let value = 3; 3 => 3 > 0;  3 => 3 - 1) {
console.log(3)
}`

trying to say this out loud
"let value equal 3, if test is true, subtract 1 from n, then console.log(n)"

Comment: @Stakvino What's wrong with it? It's perfect for beginners imo.

Comment: @Perchitti Yes, the `test` function returns a boolean. The test is whether the value `n` is greater than `0`.

Comment: @Bergi i disagree there is a lot of Js learning resources that are way better for beginners then eloquent javascript, but if the person have some programming understanding this is an amazing book to learn Js.

Comment: @Bergi what JS resources do you recommend?

Comment: @Spaghetti https://www.sitepoint.com/premium/books/javascript-novice-to-ninja-2nd-edition is a great book for beginners

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `for` loop consists of 4 parts:

- Initialization - this is run at the beginning of the loop; it usually initializes the variable(s) used in the Condition and Repetition parts.
- Condition - This is executed before each iteration. If its value is truthy, the body is then executed; otherwise, the loop stops immediately.
- Repetition - This is executed after each body execution, and usually updates variable tested by the Condition.
- Body - This is just ordinary code that's executed each time through the loop. It usually makes use of the variable(s) updated by the other parts.

The syntax is:

```
for (Initialization; Condition; Repetition) {
    Body
}
```

So in your example, the Initialization sets the current loop value (the `value` variable) to the value that was given to the function.

The Condition then executes `test(value)` function. The `for` loop will automatically test whether this returns true or false -- if it returns `false` the loop stops. This fulfills the requirement:

> Each iteration, it first runs the test function on the current loop value and stops if that returns false.

Then the Body is executed, and this executes `body(value)`. This implements the requirement:

> Then it calls the body function, giving it the current value.

Then the Repetition executes `value = update(value)`, which implements:

> Finally, it calls the update function to create a new value and starts from the beginning.

Comment: This is well laid out and exactly the walkthrough I was looking for. Thank you @Barmar

Answer (score 0):

"For loops" are a built-in feature common to programming languages, including JavaScript. The [Wikipedia article about them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_loop) is pretty thorough, and I'd start there if you wanted to [understand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_loop) the context of the question.

The exercise at hand, then, is to write a function in JavaScript that roughly-speaking provides similar features to the built-in "for loop".

The solution you quoted defines a function ("loop") that accepts four parameters: an initial value ("start"); a function that runs at before each iteration, to test whether the loop should stop ("test"); a function that will be run after each iteration ("update"); and the function that should be run in the body of the loop during each iteration ("body"). It then uses an **actual** for loop to perform the requested iterations.

Comment: Thank you! This is a great walkthrough, makes much more sense now.

Comment: What does this answer say that isn't already in the description of the problem? How does it explain how the solution works?

Comment: @Barmar As I am learning I am looking to articulate my code more thoroughly, this lays out the description very clearly. It does not address the solution, however now that I have moved through this a bit more. How does ...... 
**Finally, it calls the update function to create a new value and starts from the beginning** 
....translate into this .... 
`value = update(value)`.   ?

Comment: @Spaghetti I upvoted Barmar's answer as it goes into more detail than my own. You should post this follow-up question regarding `value = update(value)` to his answer instead of mine, if he didn't already answer it there.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to understand this myself while reading this...but from what I grasp from it it sounds like the author is trying to teach you one of two things.

1. That a for loop consists of a

   for(initialExpression; condition; incrementExpression){ 
   and then the statement 
   }
2. That you can create your own reusable customizable loop function that can function like forEach() or how ever you would like it to function.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Solving this with a for loop seems awkward, I understand why you are confused, just like me -  I'm noob too :)

Here's a recursive solution, hopefully it will shed more light, if you haven't completely figured stuff out:

```
function loop(value, test, update, execute) {
   if (!test(value)) return; // stop
   execute(value);
 return loop(update(value), test, update, execute);
}
```